# Filter and sort an ArrayCollection by another array

Tags: apache-flex

I have one array of about 10 items and an array collection of about 200 items. The array collection will contain the first 10 items somewhere in there.

I would like to filter the array collection and order it to only show the items in the first array and in the order the first array lists them in.

```
<s:ArrayCollection id="baseballCardCollection" >
    <fx:Object name="Bill"/>
    <fx:Object name="Jill"/>
    <fx:Object name="Phil"/>
    <fx:Object name="Luke"/>
    <fx:Object name="Duke"/>
    <fx:Object name="Zach"/>
    <fx:Object name="John"/>
    <fx:Object name="Don"/>
    <fx:Object name="Ron"/>
    <fx:Object name="Anne"/>
    <fx:Object name="Mark"/>
    <fx:Object name="Clark"/>
</s:ArrayCollection>
```

Filter and sort in order by:

```
<fx:Array>
  <fx:String>Zach</fx:String>
  <fx:String>Anne</fx:String>
  <fx:String>John</fx:String>
  <fx:String>Mark</fx:String>
  <fx:String>Luke</fx:String>
</fx:Array>
```

Goal:

```
<s:ArrayCollection id="baseballCardCollection" >
    <fx:Object name="Zach"/>
    <fx:Object name="Anne"/>
    <fx:Object name="John"/> 
    <fx:Object name="Mark"/>       
    <fx:Object name="Luke"/>        
</s:ArrayCollection>
```

Comment: The item of the second array will always be present in the first? If this is so, because you do not you built a third array? Because when you do the sort, you'll have to just do a little search algorithm, which would be the end of the same features you'd need to load the new array directly.

Answer (score 1):

You need to apply filter function for arraycollection then put your logic into filter function. Item will be available in arraycollection if filter function return TRUE else item will removed from arraycollection but still avaliable in `ArrayCollection.source` property ie `baseballCardCollection.source`

```
 <fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import mx.collections.Sort;
        import mx.collections.SortField;
        import mx.events.FlexEvent;

        protected function windowedapplication1_creationCompleteHandler(event:FlexEvent):void
        {       
            fitlerByPersonArray();
            sortItemsByName();
        }

        private function fitlerByPersonArray():void {               
            baseballCardCollection.filterFunction = filterByPersonAndAddOrder;
            baseballCardCollection.refresh()
        }

        private function sortItemsByName():void{
            var srt:Sort = new Sort();
            var orderField:SortField = new SortField("order");
            orderField.numeric = true;

            srt.fields = [orderField]; //Order by 

            baseballCardCollection.sort = srt;
            baseballCardCollection.refresh();
        }           

        private function filterByPersonAndAddOrder(item:Object):Boolean
        {
            var index:int = personArray.indexOf(item.name);

            if(index > -1 ){
                item.order = index; //Create new property called Order then sort with the help of order property
                return true;
            }

            return false;                   
        }

    ]]>
</fx:Script>
<fx:Declarations>
    <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
    <s:ArrayCollection id="baseballCardCollection" >
        <fx:Object name="Bill"/>
        <fx:Object name="Jill"/>
        <fx:Object name="Phil"/>
        <fx:Object name="Luke"/>
        <fx:Object name="Duke"/>
        <fx:Object name="Zach"/>
        <fx:Object name="John"/>
        <fx:Object name="Don"/>
        <fx:Object name="Ron"/>
        <fx:Object name="Anne"/>
        <fx:Object name="Mark"/>
        <fx:Object name="Clark"/>
    </s:ArrayCollection>

    <fx:Array id="personArray">
        <fx:String>Zach</fx:String>
        <fx:String>Anne</fx:String>
        <fx:String>John</fx:String>
        <fx:String>Mark</fx:String>
        <fx:String>Luke</fx:String>     
    </fx:Array>

</fx:Declarations>

<s:List dataProvider="{baseballCardCollection}" labelField="name" width="200" height="400">     
</s:List>
```

Comment: The sort of the array is important. It's not alphabetical but based on the array we are using to filter.